# Not able to perform mass insertion in redis

Tags: redis

I am working on centos 6. I want to perform mass insertion into redis cache from mySQL table that has more than 10 million records. I have already read about redis protocol and its format. I am able to copy table data into redis protocol format in text file. But when I try to execute pipe command an error is coming.

```
Error reading from the server: Connection reset by peer
```

or

```
ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got '3'
```

I am using following command:

```
cat insert.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

insert.txt contains data in this format:

```
*3
$3
SET
$2
K1
$2
V1
```

If possible,please tell me format for multiple commands in this text file as in above example, this file only contains one set command. I will be thankful if you will give me example of text file which has at least two commands in it.

I have also tried file data in this format.

```
"*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n"
```

It gives the following error:

```
ERR unknown command '*3  $3  SET  $3  key  $5  value  '
```

Comment: "\r\n" means you need the cr and lf characters there - did you use them?

Answer (score 0):

Right, so it's really important that you send the data with `CRLF` line separators -- *not* the string `\r\n` but actually those characters. This means no regular unix line endings, which is just `LF`, or `\n`.

How you insert those is depending on the editor you use, but the easiest way to work with what you have would be to have each symbol on it's own line:

```
*3
$3
SET
$2
K1
$2
V2
```

And use `sed`:

```
cat insert.txt | sed 's/$/\r/g' | redis-cli --pipe
```

Should do the trick.

Then, in order to send many commands in one go (pipelining), you just add that to the end of your file, like so:

```
*3
$3
SET
$2
K1
$2
V2
*3
$3
SET
$2
K2
$2
V3
```

Comment: thanks linus..I used this trick.ouput was....All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR unknown command '2'
ERR unknown command '$4'
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'echo' command
ERR unknown command '$öà%~é²¿ÃÆÃÖL¯«7g'
No replies for 30 seconds: exiting.
errors: 6, replies: 7
But i am getting these key's value when using get command.Can you tell me whats going on here?I mean it is showing error but working fine.

Comment: It looks like you are sending invalid data. That is, that some of your data is missing an argument or is off in some such way. Perhaps missing a dollar sign before a digit (the unknown command ´2´) and then everything is thrown off. The last error with the weird string looks like it has to do with this: `Once there is no more data to read from stdin, it sends a special ECHO command with a random 20 bytes string` from [the docs](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert).